# Where is the implementation of Array.map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Scala collections (e.g. [2.11](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection) or [2.12](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection)), where can I find the code that gets executed when an `Array` is `map`ped?

i.e.

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
val b = a.map(_ * 5)   // <--- here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [`TraversableLike`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/f8d6814bb4fb0248d6121335e67eee8fde7ce455/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L227).

When methods such as `map` are called on arrays, an implicit conversion to `ArrayOps` kicks in (e.g. `Predef.intArrayOps`), which in turn derives these methods from `SeqLike` / `TraversableLike` through inheritance.